# Pandas issue iterating over DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using pandas to scrape a web page and iterate through a DataFrame object.  Here's the function I'm calling:

```
def getTeamRoster(teamURL):
    teamPlayers = []
    table = pd.read_html(requests.get(teamURL).content)[4]
    nameTitle = '\n\t\t\t\tPlayers\n\t\t\t' 
    ratingTitle = 'SinglesRating'
    finalTable = table[[nameTitle, ratingTitle]][:-1]
    print(finalTable)
    for index, row in finalTable:
        print(index, row)
```

I'm using the syntax advocated here:

```
http://www.swegler.com/becky/blog/2014/08/06/useful-pandas-snippets/
```

However, I'm getting this error:

```
File "SquashScraper.py", line 46, in getTeamRoster
    for index, row in finalTable:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

For what it's worth, my finalTable prints as this:

```
   \n\t\t\t\tPlayers\n\t\t\t  SinglesRating
0                Browne,Noah           5.56
1             Ellis,Thornton           4.27
2                 Line,James           4.25
3          Desantis,Scott J.           5.08
4           Bahadori,Cameron           4.97
5              Groot,Michael           4.76
6              Ehsani,Darian           4.76
7                 Kardon,Max           4.83
8                 Van,Jeremy           4.66
9     Southmayd,Alexander T.           4.91
10        Cacouris,Stephen A           4.68
11         Groot,Christopher           4.62
12       Mack,Peter D. (sub)           3.94
13      Shrager,Nathaniel O.           0.00
14       Woolverton,Peter C.           4.06
```

which looks right to me.

Any idea why python doesn't like my syntax?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to try this:

```
for index, row in finalTable.iterrows():
    print(index, row)
```